# Select only statment ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: database, oracle

I'm not an Oracle developer. We have a job with steps which retrieve data from Oracle and publish (update and insert) it into another database. The weird problem is in the select query which gives error

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

after investigating the query was

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_STATUS, CUST_ACCT_CREATION_DATE,.... FROM table_CUSTOMER
```

and when I remove certain columns from the query it gives me results with no problems, but unfortunately these columns is needed for other purposes.

How can these columns generate this error?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

How? Because they don't make a distinct result set, that's how.

If you need to fetch a single row, apply `WHERE` clause to that query which will make sure that only one row is returned.

The simplest way to restrict number of rows is to use `WHERE rownum = 1`, but it'll return one, random row. Will it satisfy business rules? I don't know. Maybe; maybe not.

We don't have your tables nor data. But, if you could provide test case, someone might assist.

Comment: but i don't need a single row, the query should fetch all the data in the table

Comment: Do you know how difficult it is to debug code you can't see?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER_STATUS, CUST_ACCT_CREATION_DATE, TRADE_CHANNEL, PRICE_CLASS, SALESMAN, PARTY_NAME, CHANNEL, SUBCHANNEL,CUSTCATEGORY, SITE, SITE_NAME,  CUST_SITE_STATUS, CUST_SITE_CREATION_DATE, SITE_USE_STATUS, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, ADDRESS4, PO_BOX_NUMBER, CITY,  PAYMENT_TYPE, PAYMENT_TERM_CODE, DELIVERY_STOP2,  DELIVERY_PRIORITY, SERVICE_PATTERN, CUSTOMER_VISITS, BL_CUST_REF, BL_SITE_REF
FROM CUSTOMER

this is the full query

Comment: even if i wrote select * from CUSTOMER it gives me the error

Comment: This query, as it is, can't return TOO-MANY-ROWS. It might (and probably will) return several rows, but that wont' cause the error. Is it part of some other query, procedure, cursor, whatever?

Comment: no it's standalone query and that's why i can't get the error this is very weird to me

Comment: Huh, then you have a serious problem. Which database version is it? Which tool do you use to select data (SQLPlus? SQL Developer? Something else?).

Comment: You're probably only showing us one-half of the query.  You said a job copies data from one database to another. I'm guessing this select is only one part of the query used to update the target database; and, it should only return one row.

Comment: @gregory, two comments above it is being said that "it's standalone query".

Comment: @Littlefoot I think the OP is confused/wrong when they say "it is a standalone query" since by definition it couldn't copy data from one database to another.

Comment: I wouldn't know, @gregory. Maybe you're right. I know only what I've been told. I don't stand behind OP's shoulder and can't see what's going on.

Comment: @gregory the error happens on this statement, I used toad, connected to the server and ran this query and it's error

Comment: Is `CUSTOMER` a view?

Comment: the insert step happens in the next step which not started since the error in the step of retreiving

Comment: it's getting weirder, when i changed the user the query ran without errors